# Sort a set of multidimensional arrays by array elements

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Let's say I've started here:

```
$arr[0] = array('a' => 'a', 'int' => 10);
$arr[1] = array('a' => 'foo', 'int' => 5);
$arr[2] = array('a' => 'bar', 'int' => 12);
```

And I want to get here:

```
$arr[0] = array('a' => 'foo', 'int' => 5);
$arr[1] = array('a' => 'a', 'int' => 10);
$arr[2] = array('a' => 'bar', 'int' => 12);
```

How can I sort the elements in an array by those elements' elements?

Multidimensional arrays always feel like a little bit more than my brain can handle (-_-) (until I figure them out and they seem super easy)

Comment: Lots of duplicates. Please have a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+sort+multidimensional+array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to order them by the value of the "int" key ?

Use *uasort* with a callback function :

```
function compare_by_int_key($a, $b) {
    if ($a['int'] == $b['int']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['int'] < $b['int']) ? -1 : 1;
}
uasort($arr, "compare_by_int_key");
```

Comment: Alt.: `function compare_by_int_key($a, $b) { return $a['int'] - $b['int']; }`

Answer (score 1):

PHP has come along way since 2010.  From PHP7, the spaceship operator took a lot of convolution out of three-way sorting.

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b){ return $a['int'] <=> $b['int']; });
```

From PHP7.4, "arrow function" syntax removed some bloat from the process.

```
usort($arr, fn($a, $b) => $a['int'] <=> $b['int']);
```

Built into the magic of the spaceship operator is the fact that it will compare numeric strings as numeric type values and compare strings as strings.

Further awesomeness includes the fact that if you want to state multiple sorting rules, you only need to build a balanced array on both sides of the operator.

```
                          // sort by "int" values ASC, then "a" values ASC
usort($arr, fn($a, $b) => [$a['int'], $a['a']] <=> [$b['int'], $b['a']]);
```

Online demos of above: https://3v4l.org/QjNg7

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't forget to change the index variable you are using to reference the array because right now you only have two elements in the base array because you assign a value to $arr[1] twice.

Here is a the code:

```
// for the number of elements in the base array
for ( $eye = 0; $eye < sizeOf($arr); $eye += 1) {
    // grab each element in the array
    for ( $jay = 0; $jay < sizeOf($arr); $jay += 1) {
        // if the second element of the base array's current element
        // is greater than the next one
        if ( $arr[$jay][1] > $arr[$jay + 1][1] ) {
            // then swap those values
            $temp = $arr[$jay]
            $arr[$jay] = $arr[$jay+1]
            $arr[$jay+1] = $temp
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind I didn't test this code so you may have to do a small amount of debugging. This should sort the way you want it to, there are faster ways to perform this search but this is the simplest and I tried to give you some explanation in the comment code.