# php usort multidimensional array order by price asc

Tags: php, arrays, usort

I have an array with a structure like this
$product_array sample=

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [title] => M-SPA Super Camaro B-150 6-Person Inflatable Bubble Spa
            [image] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41F6FuitoYL._SL160_.jpg
            [link] => http://www.amazon.com/stuff
            [price] => 960.01
            [merchant] => amazon
            [discount] => 16
            [brand] => M-SPA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => M Spa Model B-130 Camaro Hot Tub, 71 by 71 by 28-Inch, Gray
            [image] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41zQwjaPqOL._SL160_.jpg
            [link] => http://www.amazon.com/stuff
            [price] => 695.01
            [merchant] => amazon
            [discount] => 
            [brand] => M-SPA
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => M-SPA B-121 4-Person Inflatable Bubble Spa, Castello
            [image] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41gnYSSVD5L._SL160_.jpg
            [link] => http://www.amazon.com/stuff
            [price] => 1,016.25
            [merchant] => amazon
            [discount] => 
            [brand] => M-SPA
        )
```

I cannot order this array with the price lowest to highest..
This code is not working

```
function order_by_price($a, $b) {
  if ($a['price'] == $b['price']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['price'] < $b['price']) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($product_array,order_by_price);
```

What am I missing
Thanks

Comment: What is the result that you receive back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a set of multidimensional arrays by array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915705/sort-a-set-of-multidimensional-arrays-by-array-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You have a non-well formed numeric value in the last array element `... [price] => 1,016.25 ...`.
 It's a "*money format*" and should be presented as a string: `[price] => "1,016.25"`.
Also, there's a certain caution with `usort` parameters:

> **Caution**: Returning non-integer values from the comparison function,
>   such as float, will result in an internal cast to integer of the
>   callback's return value. So values such as 0.99 and 0.1 will both be
>   cast to an integer value of 0, which will compare such values as
>   equal.

After proper replacing(formatting) change your code as shown below:

```
function order_by_price($a, $b) {
    $floats = str_replace(",", "", [$a['price'], $b['price']]);
    return ($floats[0] == $floats[1])? 0 : (($floats[0] < $floats[1]) ? -1 : 1);
}

usort($product_array,"order_by_price");
```

The above will work as expected ...